# Using ngrams instead of wildcards without a predefined schema

Tags: elasticsearch

I recently discovered that I shouldn't be using wildcards for elasticsearch queries. Instead, I've been told I should use ngrams. In my experimentation, this has worked really well. What I'd like to do is be able to tell Elasticsearch to use ngrams for all mapped fields (or mapped properties that fit a specific patern).
For example:

```
CURL -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test-ngram-7/' -d '{
     "mappings": {
         "person": {
             "properties": {
                 "name": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "analyzer": "partial"
                 }
             }
         }
     },
     "settings": {
         "analysis": {
             "filter": {
                 "lb_ngram": {
                     "max_gram": 10,
                     "min_gram": 1,
                     "type": "nGram"
                 }
             },
             "analyzer": {
                 "partial": {
                     "filter": [
                         "standard",
                         "lowercase",
                         "asciifolding",
                         "lb_ngram"
                     ],
                     "type": "custom",
                     "tokenizer": "standard"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }'
```

Now, when I add this mapping:

```
CURL -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test-ngram-7/person/1' -d '{
 "name" : "Cobb",
 "age" : 31
 }'
```

I can easily query for "obb" and get a partial result. In my app, I don't know in advance what fields people will be mapping. I could obviously short circuit this on the client side and declare my mapping before posting the document, but it would be really cool if I could do something like this:

```
CURL -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test-ngram-7/' -d '{
     "mappings": {
         "person": {
             "properties": {
                 "_default_": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "analyzer": "partial"
                 }
             }
         }
     },
     "settings": {
         "analysis": {
             "filter": {
                 "lb_ngram": {
                     "max_gram": 10,
                     "min_gram": 1,
                     "type": "nGram"
                 }
             },
             "analyzer": {
                 "partial": {
                     "filter": [
                         "standard",
                         "lowercase",
                         "asciifolding",
                         "lb_ngram"
                     ],
                     "type": "custom",
                     "tokenizer": "standard"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }'
```

Note that I'm using "*default*". It would also be cool if I could do like "name.*" and all properties starting with name would get filtered this way. I know elasticsearch supports *default* and wildcards.*, so I'm hoping that I'm just doing it wrong.

In short, I'd like for new properties to get run through ngram filters when mappings are created *automatically*, not using the mapping API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a dynamic_template, see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/root-object-type.html for info.

Using this, you can create mapping templates for your not-known field, based on a match, pattern-matching etc, and apply analyzers etc for these templates. This will give you more fine-grained control of the behavior compared to setting the default analyzer. The default analyzer should typically be used for basic stuff like "lowercase" and "asciifolding", but if you are certain that you wih to apply the nGram for ALL fields, it certainly a valid way to go.

Comment: Thanks, helpful info about patterns.

Answer (score 0):

So, One solution I've found is to set up a "default" analyzer. The docs says

> Default Analyzers An analyzer is registered under a logical name. It
>   can then be referenced from mapping definitions or certain APIs. When
>   none are defined, defaults are used. There is an option to define
>   which analyzers will be used by default when none can be derived.
>
> The default logical name allows one to configure an analyzer that will
>   be used both for indexing and for searching APIs. The default_index
>   logical name can be used to configure a default analyzer that will be
>   used just when indexing, and the default_search can be used to
>   configure a default analyzer that will be used just when searching.

Here is an example:

```
CURL -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test-ngram-7/' -d '{

     "settings": {
         "analysis": {
             "filter": {
                 "lb_ngram": {
                     "max_gram": 10,
                     "min_gram": 1,
                     "type": "nGram"
                 }
             },
             "analyzer": {
                 "default": {
                     "filter": [
                         "standard",
                         "lowercase",
                         "asciifolding",
                         "lb_ngram"
                     ],
                     "type": "custom",
                     "tokenizer": "standard"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }'
```

And then this query will work:

```
CURL -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test-ngram-7/person/_search' -d '{
  "query":
 {
     "match" : {
         "name" : "obb"
     }
 }
 }'
```

Answering my own question because I am still interested if this is the "correct" way to do this.